# How to disable edit button in specific row in Listview

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, listview

I have an asp net web form and i need to disable button in specific row in asp net listview. I need to disable button when i have in listview row column `Status = "Reject"`  for this row(only for this row, not for all listview)
I understand how to find it from codebehind , and how to disable it in aspx page , but i don't understand how to disable it for specific row .
**How Can i  disable edit button in specific row in Listview ?**
My code and what i tried below :

```
     <asp:ListView ID="ListView2" ItemType="DocCat.Models.Inf"  DataKeyNames="Id" EnableViewState="false"  runat="server" OnItemDataBound="ListView2_ItemDataBound" >
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <div class="outerContainer">
                <table id="docTable">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                  <th>ID</th><th>Name</th>
<th>Status</th></tr>
                        </thead> <tbody runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder"></tbody></table> </div> </LayoutTemplate>
<ItemTemplate ><tr> <td><%# Item.ID %></td> <td><%# Item.F2 %></td>
         <td><%# Item.Status %></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="YesBtn" runat="server" Text="Bla"   CommandName="Update" Onclick="YesBtn_Click"  /> </td>
                 <td><asp:Button ID="NoBtn" runat="server" Text="Bla" CommandName="Update"  Onclick="NoBtn_Click"  />
                     </td></tr> </ItemTemplate></asp:ListView>
```

**I tried to make it like this:**

```
 `<asp:Button ID="YesBtn"  Visible='<%# (Eval("ReqStatus") == "Reject" )?true:false %> ' ...  />
```

**This disable button in all listview in i have this status

And i tried like this :**

```
 protected void ListView2_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e){
           {
            if (e.Item == null) return;
            Button btn1 = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("YesBtn");
            btn1.Visible = false;
```

I don't know how to add specific row information to this .
Asp.Net Web form Entity framework c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to iterate a loop through the `ListView` and get the index of the status column. Finally do something like the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ListView1.Items.Count(); i++)
{
    //Get the Label by row
    Label label1 = (Label)ListView1.Items[i].FindControl("label1");
}
```

See this for more - [Loop Through ListView](https://chanmingman.wordpress.com/2011/02/12/loop-iterate-through-listview-items-asp-net-code-and-video/)

**Updated:** Default.aspx

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="ListView1_ItemDataBound">
      <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="label2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("name") %>'></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="label3" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Status") %>'></asp:Label>
            <asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" Text="Add" Enabled='<%# Eval("Status").ToString() == "1" %>' />
            <br />
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Default.aspx.cs: Just paste the below code in the code-behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListView1.DataSource = GetAllUsers();
        ListView1.DataBind();
    }

    public class User
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }

    public List<User> GetAllUsers()
    {
        User aUser = new User();

        List<User> Users = new List<User>();

        Users.Add(new User() { ID = 1, name = "AT-2016", Status = "1" } );
        Users.Add(new User() { ID = 2, name = "AT-2014", Status = "0" } );

        return Users;
    }

    protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ListView1.Items.Count(); i++)
        {
            //Get the Label by row
            Label status = (Label)ListView1.Items[i].FindControl("label3");
            Button button1 = (Button)ListView1.Items[i].FindControl("button1");

            if (status.Text == "1")
            {
                button1.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                button1.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Sample output:

[image: ListView_Button_Disable]

Comment: Using the above, it'll disable the button for that specific row if it has column value **Rejected**.

Comment: Sorry , but i have web form , not a windows form. In this case, how can i update your code, or it can be made only by adding   System.Windows.Forms namespace?

Comment: SubItems and index - this is from Windows.Forms

Comment: Edited the post. Check now and it'll work this time perfectly :D

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<asp:Button Visible='<%# Eval("ReqStatus").ToString() == "Reject" %>' runat="server" Text="Button1" ID="YesBtn" />
```

Comment: I guess, that should be not equal to like this: `Visible='<%# Eval("ReqStatus").ToString() != "Reject" %>'`

Comment: @AT-2016 Yea, it's work .Can you tell me plz - what method is better - in codebehind, or this?

Comment: Both methods are perfect @Андрей Голубцов. You can use any of them.